# Chained :nth-child and :nth-of-type selectors not working on chained classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've created the following JSFiddle to illustrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/bj3y34op

As you can see I'm using the following selectors to target children with the both the .result and .selected classes within different nth-child ranges.

```
<style>
.result.selected:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3) {
    background-color: red;
}
.result.selected:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) {
    background-color: green;
}
.result.selected:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9) {
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>

<div class="result"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result selected"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

In total there are only 6 items with both the .result and .selected classes. What I would expected to see is the first three items with both classes to have a red background, the next three to have a green background. However, as you can see it doesn't happen, instead the green background is only applied to items with both classes that are within the first three items with just the class .result.

Am I just using it wrongly?

Using :nth-of-type gives the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/bj3y34op/5/

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry duplication - hadn't come across that when searching... back to the drawing board :)

Comment: No worries - duplicates aren't necessarily a bad thing, as they can serve as signposts for future searchers.